# Bash script throwing "command not found" from Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, sidekiq

I just created a Rails application (version 4.1.0.beta1) and was trying to use Sidekiq to perform sobe asynchronous jobs.

The job was to execute a bash script BUT for every command in that script I'm getting "command to found" like there were no `$PATH` for Sidekiq child process.

Just to make it clear, Sidekiq finds and executes the script, but inside the script there are commands like `mkdir` and `convert` that are throwing "command not found".

I'm lost. Is there any options I have to setup to make external scripts work with Sidekiq ?

It's as simple as that:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(name)
    `/path/to/my/script #{name}`
  end
end
```

Comment: is permission  `+x` for `/path/to/my/script`?

Comment: Yes, it is. When called manually it works just fine.